# Is it true that if the pushforward of a coherent sheaf is locally free, then the original sheaf is locally free?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves, vector-bundles

I think the title says it all.  If I have a finite map $p:X\to Y$ between schemes, and $F$ is a coherent sheaf on $X$ such that $p_*F$ is locally free, can I conclude that $F$ is locally free?

Assumptions I would be happy to make:

1. The map $p$ is flat.
2. $X$ and $Y$ are both $\mathbb{A}^n$.

> I would be much more pleased with a reference than a proof, since I would like to use this result in a paper.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reference is "Auslander-Buchsbaum formula".  What matters is that $X$ and $Y$ are smooth of some common pure dimension $n$ (which forces flatness due to the quasi-finiteness, by the way), not that one has global affine spaces.  Then every coherent sheaf on $X$ has stalks with *finite* projective dimension, and so all of projective dimension zero (= locally free) precisely when the depth of each stalk is equal to the dimension of its support on the local ring. A length-$n$ regular sequence at $p(x) \in Y$ exists by the local freeness on the base, and that's such a sequence at $x$ provided that the successive quotients arising in the definition of "regular sequence" really remain *nonzero* when localizing upstairs.

The completion of the $p(x)$-stalk of the pushforward is the product of the completions at the points of $p^{-1}(p(x))$, so each factor module is free and hence we're OK as long as such factor modules are all nonzero since we can use a regular sequence in the completed local ring at $p(x)$.  So we have to rule out the possibility of a vanishing completed stalk, or equivalently a vanishing stalk, upstairs.  In such cases, upon passing to connected=irreducible components, the coherent sheaf $F$ would vanish on a Zariski-dense open upstairs, and hence on some $p^{-1}(U)$ for a dense open $U$ in the base.  Then $p_ {\ast}(F)$ would vanish on $U$ and hence vanish by local freeness, so $F = 0$. The case $F = 0$ is easy to handle directly.

Answer (score 9):

Since you asked for reference, here are some references that may be helpful  (the question is local):

1) (EDITED: Thanks to BCnrd for keeping me honest here!) If $(R,m)\to (S,n)$ is a map of  Cohen-Macaulay local rings of same dimensions, $N$ a finite $S$-module which is $R$-<strike>free</strike> flat then $${\rm{depth}}_ S N ={\rm{depth}} R = {\rm{depth}} S.$$

This follows from Prop 1.2.16 and Theorem A.11 of Bruns-Herzog "Cohen-Macaulay rings". Namely, take $M=R$ in both results, one get from A.11 that $\dim_SN = \dim_RN + \dim_SN/mN$, so $\dim_SN/mN=0$, then 1.2.16 gives  ${\rm{depth}}_SN = {\rm{depth}} R$.

2) If $S$ is regular, then f.g modules with maximal depth are free.

This is well-known. It follows from Auslander-Buchsbaum formula, as Boyarsky pointed out.

EDIT: Just to be clear, it is enought to assume: $f$ is finite, $X$ regular, and $Y$ Cohen-Macaulay scheme (certainly true if $Y$ also regular or smooth, but is a much weaker condition). For example the map induced by $k[x,y]/(xy) \to k[x]$ by killing $y$ works.

Comment: Hailong, in (1) it is restrictive to demand *finiteness* while also requiring $S$ to be local (rather than just semi-local).  For example, in the chosen answer an extra argument with completions is needed to pass to the "finite local" case from the "finite semi-local" case.  So for the CM case (in which case the trick of "connected=irreducible" is less relevant), it is better (for purpose of "global" applications) to take $S$ just semi-local and then need more argument to get to the local case.  Does your CM reference apply verbatim for $R$-flat (?) semi-local $S$? 

Comment: BCnrd: The reference does *not* require $S$ to be $R$-flat. If $S$ is semi-local, can't we just localize at each maximal ideal of $S$? 

Comment: @BCnrd: Also, may be EGA has some better reference? If you know, please share with us. Thanks. 

Comment: Hailong, I am surprised the CM reference does not require flatness.  Anyway, if you just localize at top then you lose the *finiteness* hypothesis; that's why I asked about weakening to semi-local (and it is the reason completions -- or henselizations -- would have to intervene, as in the accepted answer, to bust apart semi-local into a direct product of locals).  As for EGA ref., let me get back to you about that...

Comment: Hailong, assuming regular upstairs and CM downstairs, the proof in the accepted answer works without any need for flatness! As for relevant EGA references, not much to say.  They prove Auslander-Buchsbaum only in the regular case (all we need) in $0_ {\rm{IV}}$, 17.3.4 (so a rare case when EGA missed optimal generality; for shame), and then 17.3.5(i) says the obvious conclusion that local freeness on top amounts to have full depth on stalks. But to verify that condition, one has to go through the argument in the accepted answer, adapted to the weaker hypotheses; so EGA is useless (for this).

Comment: That's right, I never assume flatness. Anyway, I checked the references in Bruns-Herzog more carefully and I don't think we need finiteness, but need same dimension. I edited my answer, hope it is OK now. 

Comment: I am surprised EGA does not have this! 

Comment: Hailong, I still object to your imposition of finiteness condition on the module when the ring is local upstairs.  It is more natural to impose "semi-local" (and dimension conditions), since when you localize on top without completing then you will lose the $R$-finite/freeness. As for EGA being useless, I stand corrected: IV$_2$, 6.3.4 gives the required result under precisely the CM and regularity hypotheses you suggest, and applies under the semi-local hypotheses which I keep urging (since it only requires finiteness on *fibers*, which is the "right" condition). Grothedieck wins again!

Comment: I see what you mean now, it was not about the finiteness of the map!  Thanks for all the comments.  

Comment: @BCnrd: perhaps you can post the EGA reference as an answer, as the OP really wanted a reference?   

Comment: Hailong, the combined reference "Auslander-Buchsbaum" (either the usual form, or just for regular rings as in the EGA ref. above) and the depth result in the EGA ref. above yield the conclusion, but really one does still need to make some arguments, especially tracking non-vanishing of stalks. So I sincerely hope Ben will state the general result with a finite map from regular to CM scheme and use  refs to give a short argument to prove the result. Even with more regularity, if he prefers, the reader deserves a (short?) argument to go from whatever refs to the conclusion he wants. 

Comment: BCnrd: I just looked at EGA IV, and 6.3.4 is precisely 1.2.16 of Bruns-Herzog, and it (or rather, the assumption of 6.3.1) assumes N finite. So I agree with you, one can not just quote EGA. 

Comment: @Hailong: The EGA 6.3.4 result only assumes $N$ is finite *over $S$*, not over $R$, so it is a natural hypothesis; BCnrd's objection was about your hypothesis of finiteness over $R$.  In other words, the EGA hypotheses are very well-behaved with respect to localization on top, whereas your earlier finiteness hypotheses over the base ring were not.  Likewise, you are still insisting on freeness rather than just flatness for $N$ over $R$, and there as well your hypothesis is ruined by localizing on $S$; EGA only requires $R$-flatness, which is preserved by such localization.  Think about it. 

Comment: @Boyarsky: Ah, that's clear, but Bruns-Herzog also only assume flatness, it is in fact the same as EGA. I fixed the word now. Thanks for clarifying it. 

Comment: My son is about to come out, so see you guys in a few weeks (-: 

Comment: Congratulations Long!

Answer (score 8):

Not without condition (2).

Our counter-example takes place inside the ring $k[t,u]$. Let $A$ be the subring $k[t^2,tu,u^2]$ and $B$ the subring $k[t^2, u^2]$ of $A$. Note that $B$ is a free $A$-module, with basis $(1, tu)$, so $\mathrm{Spec} \ A$ is flat over $\mathrm{Spec} \ B$. Let $M$ be the $A$-module of odd polynomials (those with $f(-t,-u) = - f(t,u)$).

Then $M$ is not locally free as an $A$-module. However, $M$ is free as a $B$-module, with basis $(t, u)$. Turning $M$ into a sheaf, we have a counter-example.

Comment: This nice example shows that one cannot remove the smoothness hypotheses (the natural version of condition (2)). 